# iOS in-app purchase introductory free trial with partial content access

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, app-store-connect, in-app-subscription

I am planning to restrict users to access the full feature while they are in IAP trial mode.
If the user is in trial mode, I will show only 1 or 2 items and the rest will be locked.

Is it allowed by Apple?

If I allow the user to access everything then the user will not buy the subscription and may cancel IAP while the trial is ongoing.

Comment: Nobody here is in the position of speaking on their behalf.  So ask them if necessary.

Comment: Hmm, @ElTomato  I thought maybe someone has done this before.

Comment: There have never been official words from Big A in regard to making the app a trial version.

Comment: Yeah @ElTomato, I have asked this question on apple's forum too. I am afraid to start work upon this before someone's thought on this, Apple may reject my app if they feel this is awkward.

Comment: I would hesitate too but I've seen it. The clearest example I can think of is the HBOMax app. You can't access the movies that are in theaters unless you have a paying subscription. And Disney+ has the "Premier level" to get access to their newest movies too.

Comment: Right. Thank you @lorem to write here